# Change the order of the columns based on a specific pattern

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, columnsorting

I have a data frame similar to the structure below:

[image]

I would like just to reshuffle the columns to get the following order (No computation is necessarey):

[image]

The order should be Amount, Buy, Sell for the both two sequences. I know that `Amount` fields are always numeric and the `Buy` fields contains only `Buy`, and `Sell` fields only `Sell`. There could be also further Amount03, Buy03 and Sell03 in the table, where you do not need to do any change (e.g. Right order)!
To replicate the issue, I attached the sample data frame below:

```
main = {'ID': [1,2,3],
        'Name1': ['Julius', 'Peter', 'Marcus'],
'Postcode': [58921, 69751, 60314],
'Buy01': ['Buy', 'Buy', ''],
'Sell01': ['', '', 'Sell'],
'Amount01': [1500, 1200, 3000],
'ELO': [15, 18, 15],
'Buy02': ['Buy', ' ', ''],
'Sell02': ['', 'Sell', 'Sell'],
'Amount02': [1600, 1100, 3620],
'Height': [178, 165, 174],
'Weight': [96, 85, 73],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(main, columns = ['ID', 'Name1', 'Postcode', 'Buy01', 'Sell01', 'Amount01', 'ELO',  'Buy02', 'Sell02', 'Amount02', 'Height', 'Weight'])
```

I am looking for a generic solution. Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I would like to know what is the purpose of this. The arrange of the columns is not really a big deal. It is more on the presentation side. You should always reference the columns by its name, not the position in the dataframe, when doing operations. That is one of the great advantages of pandas over plain numpy matrix for example. So consider that rearranging the columns might be not the best approach for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

This is not the full solution to your question but might be useful to spark some ideas.

In pandas you can get the columns of the dataframe with the following notation:

```py
df[['col1', 'col2']]
```

Based on that idea, you can change the order the columns are displayed too. For example in your case:

```py
>>> df[['Amount01', 'Sell01', 'Buy01']]
   Amount01 Sell01 Buy01
0      1500          Buy
1      1200          Buy
2      3000   Sell
```

You could potentially do something like this to reorder the columns:

```py
>>> columns = list(df.columns)
>>> df[sorted(columns)]
   Amount01  Amount02 Buy01 Buy02  ELO  Height  ID   Name1  Postcode Sell01 Sell02  Weight
0      1500      1600   Buy   Buy   15     178   1  Julius     58921                    96
1      1200      1100   Buy         18     165   2   Peter     69751          Sell      85
2      3000      3620               15     174   3  Marcus     60314   Sell   Sell      73
```

More ad hoc "ordering" can be done using a custom algorithm for sorting. There you can add the logic you described to sort the columns array and then get the columns sorted.